# Spring web application templates for user management

Tags: templates, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Spring Roo is pretty useful tool and i like it - you can setup basic structure of Spring project in the minutes.

I wonder if you could recommend me some Spring-based projects which could be reused partially as templates for new projects e.g. for user management.

**We would like to find API for user management where user register emails & username, where user gets email with activation, user can reset password, captcha, session timeouts etc...**

I got few results when i searched for 'Spring bootstrap' or 'Spring template' on github.

I feel that each time we start new project we have to implement stuff which is not the 'core of the app' but it`s more about other things which are necessary to do but i believe we could reuse it from some other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can have a look at typical security addon for Spring Roo.

https://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-typical-security/

I also plan on adding future versions of RooStrap to contain security features as well.

http://bhagyas.github.com/roostrap/

Cheers.